# Sitecore 7.2 Analytics DB records grown in size to 200 GB+

Tags: site-configuration, sitecore-query, sitecore-services-client

Sitecore 7.2 Analytics DB records has grown in size to 200 GB+.

Does anyone know of any recommendation for purging old data and this is a production setup so the impact of this data being removed from the database should not impact performance of live site?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to used [Analytics Database Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/A/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx?sc_lang=en)

You have to use Analytics Database Manager 2.1
This version works with: Sitecore CMS 6.5 - 7.2

These module it helps you to run next tasks :

- Clean all Analytics data
- Clean Analytics data by the specified criteria
- Remove all BOTs visitors
- Rebuild index

I recommend you to not run on live environment, make a backup of your site and bring it locally and it run tasks module.